# Does Wayland version1.0.3 support touch and windows switch?

Tags: linux, wayland

Due to project restriction, I must use Wayland ver1.0.3.
I'll develop applications on embedded system with Wayland.
I don't know whether this Wayland version support touch operation,can it manage multi window.What is the different between desktop-shell and fullscreen-shell and ivi-shell?

Answer (score 0):

`wl_touch` did exist then, but note that 1.0.3 is a very early release and a lot has happened since.

Multiple "windows" is really about multiple `wl_surface` objects in the protocol, and yes, the protocol accommodates multiple surfaces. How that is handled is up to the compositor you created for your system.

The different shells are part of Weston, not Wayland per se, (but see the ivi protocol extension) and the difference is really context. The shells are demonstrations of what can be done on desktop computers vs, say, in-vehicle-infotainment devices.